# How long to paint this house?

Tags: code-golf, math, code-challenge, array

Here is the problem, for which I can only think of an iterative solution and have not found a closed formula:

- You need to paint a house with R rooms.
- For each room there are four walls and one ceiling, which all have the same dimensions and need C coats of paint.
- You can't paint the next coat until the previous one has dried. You're finished when every wall is dry. Time taken to move between walls, ceilings, rooms is negligible.
- It takes you M1 minutes to paint each coat, and M2 minutes for the paint to dry on each. You must finish in the least possible time, otherwise they will not pay you.

**Note:** Don't forget, the paint must all be dry before you can receive your payment!

#### Inputs:

- R, C, M1, and M2, in order and delimited with any consistent separator
- R: Number of rooms in the house
- C: Coats of paint needed for each wall/ceiling
- M1: Minutes taken to paint each coat
- M2: Minutes taken for paint to dry on each coat (measured from when you've finished the entire coat)

#### Outputs:

- The hours and minutes taken to paint the entire house

#### Constraints:

- 1 ≤ R ≤ 10
- 1 ≤ C ≤ 20
- 1 ≤ M1 ≤ 10000
- 1 ≤ M2 ≤ 10000

#### Examples:

````
1 1 12 0 => 1:00

5 2 5 30 => 4:40

1 5 5 200 => 17:25
```
````

Comment: Welcome to the site! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/66833) in order to get feedback before posting to main. We also require challenges to have an objective winning criteria, such as [code-golf] or [fastest-code]. As this doesn't, I have voted to close the question

Comment: I'd recommend against strict IO rules like "input: line 1: values separated by spaces" and "output: time in the format H:MM". Generally it's better to let people use their langauge's most natural format to make the task more about the actual problem and less about boring conversion

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've tried to take your remarks into consideration and edited my post. I hope it's ok now :pray

Comment: Is this problem from another site?

Comment: This doesn't look like a good [fastest-code] challenge to me, as it's quite trivial and the winning solution will be the trivial algorithm written in C or assembly. Not much to compete there.

Comment: I like this challenge, but [code-golf] would fit better with it.

Comment: Alexbries I've changed [fastest-code] to  [code-golf] (very very sorry I'm new..)
@PurkkaKoodari Would it be possible to get this re-opened ? :pray

Comment: It's almost there, but one thing I'd like to point out is that the input and output format is a bit restrictive. [Here's](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/95792) the list of default input/output methods. Good luck, and I hope this gets reopened soon!

Comment: If I've understood correctly, It takes M1x5R minutes to paint a single coat on the whole house. Hence example 1 is 60 min for 1 coat, OK. Example 2 is 125 min per coat x 2 coats = 250 min painting time. Then to get the 280min answer we add the 30 min drying time (we can't start painting the first wall immediately, OK.) I don't follow Example 3. I get 25 min per coat x 5 coats = 125min plus 200x4 waiting = 800min. Total 925min. But the given answer is 17:25 = 1045min. As far as I can tell the formula is M1x5RxC + M2x(C-1) and example 3 is wrong. If this is so, this is rather a simple challenge.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt have you taken into account the fact that you can paint the next wall while a wall is drying ?

Comment: [Sandboxed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20684/92901)

Comment: @SimonRochwerg I did take into account the fact that you can paint the next wall while a wall is drying, but I read the rule about not finishing until the paint is dry wrong. I get the same answer as you now and will post my calculation in the sandbox

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Nice ! Can't wait to see your solution

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Any solution to post yet ? :)